# Phalcon Persistent

Tags: php, ubuntu, caching, phalcon, persistent

Can anyone tell me how I can manually destroy a persistent variable, either from my browser or the server?

I forgot to comment out the caching from the ACL plugin:

`if (!isset($this->persistent->acl)) {`

and now my app's a bit broken and I cannot render any controllers or their views. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `$this->persistent->acl = null;` should be enough

Comment: @KarlViiburg was given a great answer [here] (http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4677/destory-persistent#C15732). After adding that, I was then able to destroy the cached settings file and ensure my new settings kicked in. Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found by serializing the ACL data into a cached file system: (http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4677/destory-persistent#C15732)[http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4677/destory-persistent#C15732]